# Ten people sitting at a round table

Tags: logical-deduction

Ten people are sitting around a circular table according to the following conditions:

- There are two persons between X and U.
- Y is neither adjacent to X nor opposite T.
- P and T are adjacent to W.
- Q is opposite S who is to the right of V.
- R and W have four persons between them.
- There are two persons between R and V.

---

Find the relative positions of each person. A diagram is preferable.

---

Source: TIME.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am unable to upload images (don't know why), assume that the circle is a rectangle

So, from condition (III), we get (Let % = **Other People** and # = **Blank Space**)

> P W T 
>  % # % 
>  % # % 
>  % % % 
>  As P and T are adjacent to W

Then, from condition (V),

> P W T 
>  % # % 
>  % # % 
>  % R % 
>  As there are supposed to be 4 persons between R and W

After that, from condition (VI), we see that there are 2 possibilities :

> **No. 1** 
>  P W T 
>  V # % 
>  % # % 
>  % R % 
>  ***OR*** 
>  **No. 2** 
>  P W T 
>  % # V 
>  % # % 
>  % R %

Now, with condition (IV), possibility No. 2 can be eliminated (Big thanks to @Alconja for telling me)

> As S is supposed to be the right of V which is not possible in **No. 2**. Hence, we continue with **No.1** 
>  P W T 
>  V # Q 
>  S # % 
>  % R %

Then, with condition (I) and (II), we see that there are 2 possibilities again :

> **No.1** 
>  P W T 
>  V # Q 
>  S # X 
>  U R Y 
>  ***OR*** 
>  **No. 2** 
>  P W T 
>  V # Q 
>  S # U 
>  X R Y

Since, Y is not adjacent to X,

> **No. 2** is the only possibility

So, the final answer is

> P W T 
>  V # Q 
>  S # U 
>  X R Y

Comment: Your interpretation of "to the right" is inverted (usually it would be to the person's right, as they faced the centre of the table), which means * ends up opposite T, breaking rule *(ii)*.

Comment: hmm... lemme check @Alconja

Comment: @Alconja Thanks for telling me. Just edited the answer :D

Comment: how can you exclude that they are sitting in order T-W-P instead of P-W-T on the first line?

Comment: Hmmm, true @elias

Answer (score 7):

The final configuration is:

> ```
>    T Q U
>  W       Y
>  P       R
>    V S X
> ```

Step by step solution (where an uppercase letter is a known position, and a lowercase is a possible position):

> *(iv) Q is opposite S who is to the right of V.*
>
> ```
>    . Q .
>  .       .
>  .       .
>    V S .
> ```
>
> *(vi) There are two persons between R and V.*
>
> ```
>    r Q .
>  .       .
>  .       r
>    V S .
> ```
>
> *(v) R and W have four persons between them.*
>
> ```
>    r Q .
>  w       .
>  .       r
>    V S w
> ```
>
> *(iii) P and T are adjacent to W.*
>
> ```
>    pt Q .
>  W       .
>  pt      R
>    V S .
> ```
>
> *(i) There are two persons between X and U.*
>
> ```
>    pt Q xu
>  W       .
>  pt      R
>    V S xu
> ```
>
> *(ii) Y is neither adjacent to X nor opposite T.*
>
> ```
>    T Q U
>  W       Y
>  P       R
>    V S X
> ```

Comment: What the heck 8 seconds too late T_T

Comment: @KevinL - And I suspect we both spent more time fighting with the formatting than with the solving. :P

Comment: Lol, exactly :D

Comment: The question is - what is considered "to the right" in a circle. I was looking from the center outwards, and got the same solution in the opposite order (if yours is considered clockwise, then mine is counter-clockwise).

Comment: @Vilx- It's to the person's right. Given that "ten persons are sitting around a circular table", I'd say it's a pretty safe bet that they're facing the centre (though yes, there is some ambiguity).

Comment: @Alconja - Good point, didn't think of it that way, it makes much more sense.